# Apt-get broken after termination in mid-install

Tags: 12.04, apt

Long story short, I tried installing something via `apt-get install` and accidentally terminated the process through terminal. I now can't use `apt-get install`, Ubuntu Software Center, etc. I tried running `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`, but to no avail.

I then tried running `sudo apt-get install -f`, and got the following results:

```
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 216122 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 (using .../libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.3_i386.deb) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.3_i386.deb (--unpack): subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this error, or at least "reset" `apt-get` so I can install things again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reboot the machine. Whatever is using that file should no longer be using it after a reboot. Then run `sudo apt-get install -f` to repair it. That should work for ya.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had rebooted the machine but I forgot to run `install -f` afterwards.

Answer (score 8):

You can fix this by just run  `dpkg --purge --force-depends "package_name"` to purge a broken package then you have to run `apt-get autoremove` and `apt-get -f install`
After this, the problem will be solve.

Comment: that does removes every thing that the package brought along....but does not helps with installation error...